# tf.data.Dataset performance with tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am playing with multilabel text classification using tf.keras (tensorflow version 1.9.0).
I have a dataset consisting of 185485 train and 46372 validation examples.

For the first try (on CPU), I pre-padded the data and fed it to the model:

```
from tensorflow import keras
....
X_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=2000)

inp = keras.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], ))
x = keras.layers.Embedding(len(tk.word_index) + 1, 256, mask_zero=True)(inp)
x = keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=300, validation_split=0.2)
```

The model takes **~130 minutes** per epoch to train.

I then try to do the same with Dataset. Since my data is large, I can't fit in 2GB limit to use `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`, and I use `Dataset.from_generator()` instead

```
X_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=2000)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=777, stratify=y_train)

def gen(data, labels):
    for x, y in zip(data, labels):
        yield x, y

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: gen(X_train, y_train),
    output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32),
    output_shapes=([2000], [y_train.shape[1]]),
)

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(128)
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()

val_dataset = ...

....
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=300, steps_per_epoch=len(X_train)//128, validation_data=val_dataset,
      validation_steps=len(X_val)//128)
```

I expected the performance to be roughly the same, which is not the case, since one epoch took **~280 minutes** to train.
What am I missing? How do I achieve the same performance using the Dataset input?

Answer (score -2):

- Try `unroll=True` in LSTM layer. For detail check LSTM layer documentation on Keras website
- Or use CuDNNLSTM on GPU for further speedup

Comment: That does not quite answer my question. I'm aware that there are ways to speed up the training, like training on GPU (with or without CuDNN variant). I want to know why the training times with Dataset is so different.

Comment: because you are simply loading data in second stage from disk!? Disk I/O is the reason it is taking more time

Comment: it should be clear from the code that the dataset is already loaded in memory and not read from disk in both cases